# Doctrine Class Table Inheritance access to attributes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need join ACTIVITY table by 'type' column value to specific table (like: teamEvent, projectEvent etc.).

My select:

```
 $activity = $this
      ->getDoctrine()
      ->getRepository('TaskerWebBundle:Activity')
      ->findAll();
```

In $activity array i have object with attributes: ID(null) STATUS(string), TEAM(obj), USER_TRIGGER(obj) but missing TYPE(string) and USER(obj) - from Activity entity. How i can access this attributes?

If I use `$activity->getType()` it returns NULL.

Activity entity:

```
namespace Tasker\WebBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Activity
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tasker\WebBundle\Entity\ActivityRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"team" = "TeamEvents"})
 */

class Activity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="activities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

}
```

TeamEvents entity:

```
namespace Tasker\WebBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Tasker\WebBundle\Entity\Activity;

/**
 * TeamEvents
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tasker\WebBundle\Entity\TeamEventsRepository")
 */
class TeamEvents extends Activity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team", inversedBy="events")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="teamEvents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_trigger_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userTrigger;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set team
     *
     * @param integer $team
     * @return TeamEvents
     */
    public function setTeam($team)
    {
        $this->team = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param string $status
     * @return TeamEvents
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set userTrigger
     *
     * @param integer $userTrigger
     * @return TeamEvents
     */
    public function setUserTrigger($userTrigger)
    {
        $this->userTrigger = $userTrigger;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userTrigger
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserTrigger()
    {
        return $this->userTrigger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't get access to type property since there isn't one. That "type" you're referring to is only a field in your table, used by Doctrine. What you can do is to implement a method e.g. getType() in each of your classes and return the corresponding string.

```
class TeamEvents extends Activity{

   public function getType(){
      return 'team';
   }

}
```

And so forth.

Comment: Thank you for answer but user property is existing in activity entity (and in database table) how i can access it?

Comment: If doctrine relations are right and you properly saved your entities, you should be able to access user object via simple e.g. getUser() method. Please provide more code from your entities to see what we're dealing with :P

Comment: Code updated if you want see any more - no problem - write what.

Comment: First, what do you have $userTrigger property in TeamEvents entity twice for ? I'm surprised that didn't cause an error. Rename or remove one of them (field name too). Also, try to change your private properties from Activity entity to protected. The rest of your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Now if i get object user (->getUser) it returns - object (Proxies\__CG__\Tasker\WebBundle\Entity\User) and it haven't attributes like name, email... Do you have any hint?

Comment: I must call ->getUser()->getFirstName() and i get right value - is this ok? I think the right way is ->user->getFirstName()

Comment: You should definitely use geters and seters - that's what they are for. So instead of accessing $activity->user directly use $activity->getUser(). If you want to access $user property without method ($activity->user) you have to change the visibility of that property to public. That's highly unrecommended in OOP world.